# Android: AdMob + phonegap - network is unavailable

Tags: android, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing application on Android with phonegap 2.2. Also i already added admob to my app, but sometimes i'm get an error:

```
Received ad url: <url: "http://...."
Request scenario: Offline with no buffered ads
Network is unavailable. Aborting ad request.
```

But there is no problem with network, as i can load other resources from internet.

But sometimes it receive ads successfully - and with the same parameters can't receive later...

I configured whitelist at phonegap config: 
`<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`,
 and manifest for admob.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The same issue with cordova2.5

Comment: Cordova 3.0 checkin in, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it works sometimes and not others, this usually means that your network connection is unstable. i.e dropping in and out.

Comment: No, as i wrote there is no problem with network connection - at the same time a can receive some other data, but AdMob don't receive ads. But, for example, after reinstalling app after one minute - it already receives ads successfully

Comment: Can confirm what @Mikhail is saying, I have a good network connection and see this issue intermittently

Answer (score 1):

Made another edit/update.

I removed some items from the build path to improve the app. By doing so, I believe something went screwy with the android build path in eclipse. I removed the admob sdk from references, then readded it back by Add to Build Path. It started working again.

It also might be because I was calling back to the native code in master.js using addJavaScriptInterface and that may be causing some thread conflicts and perhaps AdMob SDK is losing it's network permission. It wouldn't be the only time I have had issues as a result of using the addJavaScriptInterface function. It is the reason why I have to target 16 because Nexus devices will no longer work properly.

Last update: After all those changes above... I was getting it off and on. It appears that there was some project corruption, even after cleaning the project a half dozen times. I ended up creating another app project from scratch and adding the admob sdk to the lib folder. This issue no longer occurs. So strange.. wish I had something more specific to share.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if the ad loading fails with a timeout.

3G data is often throttled, and it could be that particularly large ads take a while to download on a cellular data network. (especially if you are loading other external resources simulataneously)

If this is the case, you might be able to remedy the problem by setting a longer request timeout for Cordova and/or AdMob.